# iPhone core location, maps navigation

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, navigation

I've searched quite a lot and didn't find the answer, is it possible to have a map view which will navigate to specific locations?

Like integrated iPhone map application...

I want to have 3-4 addresses and when you click on one it will show directions on map how to get there, can it be done?

Comment: whats wrong with using the google direction api? http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Comment: Can you link me to example tutorial to use google api?

Answer (score 0):

No, I dont...I can google just like you :)

It looks pretty simple though - you just need to build your direction requests:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?parameters

for example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Boston,MA&destination=Concord,MA&waypoints=Charlestown,MA|Lexington,MA&sensor=false

and you get back a response in this structure, and you just need to parse the JSON object:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los+Angeles,CA&waypoints=Joplin,MO|Oklahoma+City,OK&sensor=false

Hope that helps.